# How do I delay angular animation until after model binding

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, animation

I am working on an angularJS project and I am animating between the state transitions. I used the angular wiki as a guide, including this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NsZhDL?p=preview

I am animating from one `<table>` to the next state's `<table>` The animation (it's a slide right), works fine but the animation fires before the data is loaded. So a single row of headers slides in from the right and then the data is loaded in the `<tr>`'s. In my controller I have an ajax call that goes and gets data. It's obviously getting it after the animation fires. Is there a way to make sure the data is loaded prior to the animation?

```
function CategoryList(/*dependencies*/) {
var controller = this;
//setup stuff

//get the data
$http.get('/My/Url', {
    headers: {
        ShowLoading: true
    }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    controller.setCategories(data);
});
```

One thing I have tried in my state object, is to use the resolve to go and get the data, and then return a promise, but the result is the same. Here's that attempt:

```
.state('myStateName', {
            url: '/myUrl/{id:int}',
            templateUrl: '/mytemplate.html',
            controller: 'ListController',
            controllerAs: 'List',
            resolve: {
                ajaxData: ['$q', '$http', '$stateParams', '$timeout',
                    function ($q, $http, $stateParams, $timeout) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        // $http returns a promise for the url data
                        $http.get('/Admin/Activities/Category/GetDetail/' + $stateParams.id, {
                            headers: {
                                ShowLoading: false
                            }
                        }).success(function (data) {
                            deferred.resolve(data);
                        }).error(function (data) {
                            deferred.reject();
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }]
            }
```

Again the data comes back fine, it just happens after the animation. I thought this would work because in the wiki it says "Each of the objects in resolve below must be resolved (via deferred.resolve() if they are a promise) before the controller is instantiated. " https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

**edit** After some more research I think the ajax completes before the animation, but the model binding occurs after. I believe this is the current sequence of events.

1. Click on state transition link
2. Resolve fires, getting data from server
3. Get destination state's template
4. Animate the new template into position ([ui-view]-enter yada yada)
5. Bind the new template to the model.

**edit** This was all a CSS problem, the min-height on the table's div parent was set to 1px, this caused the tbody to not show until the animation was finished.

Comment: How are you firing the animation? I'll also post about using resolve.

Comment: I have a [ui-view] selector in my css file, and ngAnimate injected into my module and it works just like that plunkr example. I don't exactly understand how it works, I don't have to have any code written to tell the animation to fire. It's just some angular magic sauce. I'm new to angular

Answer (score 0):

Plunker isn't working at the moment, but this seems to work:

```
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router", "ngAnimate"]);

    function dummyResolve(data) {
      return function ($timeout, $q) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () {
          defer.resolve(data);
        }, 500);
        return defer.promise;
      };
    }

    myapp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state("foo", {
          url: "/foo",
          template: '<h1>{{ data }}</h1>',
          controller: 'FooBarCtrl',
          resolve: {
            data: dummyResolve('foo')
          }
        })
        .state("bar", {
          url: "/bar",
          template: '<h1>{{ data }}</h1>',
          controller: 'FooBarCtrl',
          resolve: {
            data: dummyResolve('bar')
          }
        })

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/foo");
    });

    myapp.controller('FooBarCtrl', function ($scope, data) {
      $scope.data = data;
    });
```

Animations happen after the data is resolved.

Comment: I don't like using an arbitrary timeout because even if this does solve the problem, there is no way to guarantee that the data will be resolved in X msecs

Comment: @SupremeDud: the `$timeout` isn't supposed to be a solution; it's merely used to create _async_ mock function that _resolves_ test data at a later time. The timing has nothing to do with the animation -- set it to two days and you'll see that it's still working.

Comment: The result is the same here. The model is bound after the animation finishes

Comment: That's very odd -- AFAIK ng-animate kicks in after the template binding digest. The controller and associated template should be processed before any animation can occur. [I've uploaded a video to show this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwrmG1mym74&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: Ok so egg on my face here, one of our designers found a problem with the css on the wrapping div. The min-height was set to 1px, and that was causing the table body to not show. It works now. Not sure how to score these answers as the original premise to the question was flawed

Answer (score 0):

So resolve confused me at first, I for the life of me couldn't get it to work properly.

Here is the code that I am using on the project I am currently working on, this code works...

```
var getUserData = ['$q','$http',
  function($q, $http) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // You can run the code that starts your animation here, not sure how it works.
    $http.get('url')
      .success(function(data) {
        // Once it hits here it means you have your data and the resolve will complete allowing the state to change.
        // If you need your animation to run now, you would add it here
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }
      .error(function(data) {
        deferred.reject();
      }

    return deferred.promise;
  }]
```

Hopefully that helps, let me know if you need some clarification

So to give your data from the resolve to your target state controller, all you have to do is inject it into your controller

```
app.controller('someController', ['$scope', 'resolvedData',
  function($scope, resolvedData) {
    $scope.data = resolvedData // Here is your data
  }]);
```

see the ui.router docs about resolve for more info https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: It looks like the resolving of the ajax isn't really the problem. the ajax definitely finishes. I notice in dev tools that the data is retrieved before the animation fires.

Comment: So you are using ng-animate to animate between states correct? This code I have given you will work with that, just ignore the comments about the animation, you dont have to do anything. So when the state change is triggered, it will hold until it is resolved (when you get the data) and then continue on to the new state which will cause the animation to fire.

Comment: I am doing this exact thing with this code. I have edited my answer to show how to get that resolved data into your controller

Comment: I'm using this answer and although it does resolve data into the controller just fine, the animation fires before all the data is placed in the template. See http://imgur.com/gallery/qqVvna2/ and maybe that will be more clear

Comment: Can you show your html? The problem might be in there.